# dictionary not coming in for loop despite correct syntax

Tags: python, html, django, postgresql

I am doing crud project which has models PRoducts,categories,sub categories ,color,size.
I am trying to get a django dropdown using SERIALIZERS and have connect categories and subcategories via foreignkeys
below are the models

```
class Categories(models.Model):
    #made changes to category_name for null and blank
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    category_description = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```
class Products(models.Model):
    Categories = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    sub_categories = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Colors = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    Size = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'media/',width_field=None,height_field=None,null=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    price = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    sku_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    prod_details = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

```
class SUBCategories(models.Model):
    category_name = models.ForeignKey(Categories,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    sub_categories_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    sub_categories_description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    isactive = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.categories_name
```

below is the functions

```
def insert_sub_categories(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        insertsubcategories = {}
        insertsubcategories['sub_categories_name']=request.POST.get('sub_categories_name')
        insertsubcategories['sub_categories_description']=request.POST.get('sub_categories_description')
        form = SUBCategoriesSerializer(data=insertsubcategories)
        
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print("hkjk",form.data)
            messages.success(request,'Record Updated Successfully...!:)')
            print(form.errors)
            return redirect('sub_categories:show_sub_categories')
        else:
            category_dict = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
            category = CategoriesSerializer(category_dict,many=True)
            hm = {'context': category.data}
            print(hm)
            # print(form.errors)
            return render(request,'polls/insert_sub_categories.html',hm)

    else:
        category_dict = Categories.objects.filter(isactive=True)
        category = CategoriesSerializer(category_dict,many=True)
        hm = {'context': category.data}
        print(hm)
        return render(request,'polls/insert_sub_categories.html',hm)
```

below is the html

```
<select name="category_name" id="">
                                {% for c in hm %}
                                   <option value="{{c.id}}">{{c.category_name}}</option>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </select>
```

below is the image of dropdown on which no option arrives
[image]
the drop down still doesnt have any options,where am I going wrong?

Comment: editing the question is done ,only image of the dropdown which isnt coming is there

Comment: `{% for c in context %}`.

Comment: But you d not need a serializer: passing `Categories` objects is sufficient.

Comment: thanks a million Willem Van Onsem! Really appreciated the help you gave